# MySQL Query Returning Wrong ID

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to run a query in **MYSQL** to return the correct `Instructor_ID` but for some reason it is returning two values and the `instructor_ID` should be `2` not `1`.

I have a PK for `Person_ID`, which is FK for `Instructor_ID`. Previously I used group by which worked for Instructor_ID 1. Please check image.

Any help is appreciated.

[image]

Edit with table designs:

[image]

Comment: Can you post the structure of the tables? And some sample data?

Comment: It seems you are are missing a PK/FK join clause.

Comment: It's implicit, in the `FROM` clause as he selects from 2 tables, and the condition in the `WHERE` should filter his results. What he wrote there is equivalent to `SELECT * FROM T1 JOIN T2 ON 1=1`. , and then he filters these results with the `WHERE` clause

Comment: It's implicitly cartesian.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to join the two tables... `Instructor` and `People`.

Your query would be:

```
select  Instructor_ID, f_name, l_name, Person_ID
from    Instructor, People 
where   Instructor.Instructor_ID = Person.Person_ID and 
        f_name = "Betsy"
```

or

```
select  Instructor_ID, f_name, l_name, Person_ID
from    Instructor
        join People 
          on Instructor.Instructor_ID = Person.Person_ID
where   f_name = "Betsy"
```

The `group by` is not necessary.

Comment: That worked, thank you. completely forgot about making values equal to one another

Answer (score 0):

Could you please share tables' structure?

I guess you have 2 records in Instructor for this Betsy.
You can check this by running a query

```
select * from instructor where f_name = 'Betsy'
```

Btw, you should specify join condition for the both tables

```
from instructor i inner join people p on p.person_id = i.person_id
```

Also you should not use group by like this, check the manual. You need distinct in this case.

What do you want to select? I mean, for real, what is the question?

Comment: I would like to show her person id, instructor id, name, last name. it's just a query to return those values but it's bringing up the wrong id